# How do I add two independent probability functions?

Tags: probability

(Edited this to try to be clearer, again, apologies if I'm not fully making sense here.)

Let's say that I have a task that takes a random amount of time, somewhere between 1 and 2 hours, evenly distributed. It seems that the simplest way to represent this is with this function, given a value $p$ that is a random number between 0 and 1.

$$
 f_1(p_1) = p_1 + 1
$$

I can figure out intuitively that if I wanted to flip this around and get a probability density function
(I think that's what it's called?) It'd be this:

$$
     pd_1(x) = \begin{cases}
         0, & \text{if $x$ < 1} \\
         x, & \text{if 1 >= $x$ >= 2 } \\
         0, & \text{if $x$ > 2} \\
     \end{cases}
$$

First of all, is there a name for this "flipping around" operation so that I can look it up and learn more about it?

Now, let's say that I have a second, independent task, that takes between 2 and 4 hours:

$$
 f_2(p_2) = 2 p_2 + 2
$$

Probability density (again, I figured this out by guessing:)

$$
     pd_2(x) = \begin{cases}
         0, & \text{if $x$ < 2} \\
         x/2, & \text{if 2 >= $x$ >= 4 } \\
         0, & \text{if $x$ > 4} \\
     \end{cases}
$$

Now, I know that if I perform these tasks sequentially, I'll get them done somewhere between 2 and 5 hours. How can I create a single function of the form $f(p) = ?$ to tell me this (where $0 >= $p$ >= 1$)?

And how can I create a probability density function that tells me the odds of getting the task done in $x$ time?

Comment: Hello! It might help if you tell us what you are trying to do and why. Where does your problem come from? It is unusual to add probability mass functions together to get things that add up to $2$, so there may be some flaw that led to this point. Also, as you've defined them, both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the identity functions (you simply relabeled their inputs) and $f_3$ is just the addition operation. Cheers!

Comment: Your probability density functions (pdf) `pd_1` and `pd_2` don't match your description of being "uniform".  It seems like your mixing and matching probability distribution with cumulative distributions. For the pdf (prob(X=x)) it should be 0, then some constant for a period (1/length of period), then back to 0 because all non-zero times should have equal probability for it to be "uniform".  If you look at the cumulative probability (prob(X>x)) of these it would be 0, then x/(length of period), then 1 afterwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be picking a point $(X,Y)$ uniformly randomly in the rectangle $R=(1,2)\times(2,4)$ and to ask for the distribution of $Z=X+Y$. Drawing the rectangle $R$ and some regions of equations $x+y\leqslant z$ in $R$, one sees that $3\leqslant Z\leqslant6$ with full probability and that each probability $P(Z\leqslant z)$ is proportional to the area of some specific polygon included in $R$.

This yields the density $f_Z$ of $Z$ as the classical "tent" function, that is,
$$
f_Z(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac12(z-3)& \text{if} & 3\lt z\lt 4\\ \frac12& \text{if} & 4\lt z\lt 5\\ \frac12(6-z)& \text{if} & 5\lt z\lt 6\\ 0&\text{otherwise}&\end{array}\right.
$$
Recall that this means that, for every $z$,
$$
P(Z\leqslant z)=\int_{-\infty}^zf_Z(u)\,\mathrm du,
$$
and that, for every suitable function $A$,
$$
E(A(Z))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty A(u)\,f_Z(u)\,\mathrm du.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess by 'probability functions' you meant 'probability distributions'. In that case, $f_1$ and $f_2$ cannot be probability distributions, since the integral of a probability distribution in their domain must be 1 and in this case the integral is just 1/2. Besides that, your question doesn't make much sense.

I guess you might be trying to ask: If I have two random variables $x$ and $y$ with given probability distributions $P_x$ and $P_y$ and define a new variable $z$ as $z=x+y$, what is the probabiliy distribution of $z$?